# seinem oder seines?

Tags: dative, grammaticality, genitive

Habe hier gerade einen unangenehmen Satz gefunden und weiß nicht sicher was korrekt ist:

> Bystron habe in der Wahlkabine bei der Kanzlerwahl den von ihm ausgefüllten Stimmzettel samt seinem Wahlausweis fotografiert und das Foto veröffentlicht.

Zitat Spiegel.
Ich würed ja

> ... Stimmzettel samt seines Wahlausweises foto....

sagen.

Comment: Liste der Präpositionen mit Dativ: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Dativ.html

Comment: Man könnte behaupten "samt" ist hier keine Preposition, sondern eine Kunjunktion. Man kann ja das Wort ohne Bedeutungsveränderung mit "und" austauschen. Damit stünde ja "Wahlausweis" in Akkusativ, in kongruenz mit "Stimmzettel"? Oder denke ich nicht gerade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mit "samt" benutzt man den Dativ. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/samt_nebst_einschlieszlich

Comment: ja stimmt eigentlich - jetzt kommts

Answer (score 2):

Allerdings besteht vermutlich aufgrund der semantischen Ähnlichkeit zu 'inklusive' und 'einschließlich', die beide den Genitiv regieren, ein nachvollziehbarer Drall in Richtung Genitiv auch nach 'samt'. Dieser soll sich sogar, wenn man Google Ngram Viewer glauben darf, seit den 80er Jahren proportional und kontinuierlich verstärken. Google liefert eine erkleckliche Menge an Belegen für "samt seines". Auch bei 'mitsamt seinem/seines' ist nach Google Ngram Viewer die Entwicklung vergleichbar: etwas weniger Dativ und etwas mehr Genitiv in allerletzter Zeit.